# how to declare function pointer using typedef

Tags: c

```
typedef int SERVER_DISPATCH(struct _SERVER_OBJECT *pSerObj,int val);
typedef SERVER_DISPATCH *PSERVER_DISPATCH;
```

or

```
typedef int (*SERVER_DISPATCH)(struct _SERVER_OBJECT *pSerObj,int val);
typedef SERVER_DISPATCH PSERVER_DISPATCH;
```

I am trying to create function pointers using typedef,above two type of declarations are similar? can anybody explain in detail?

Comment: Hi there !! It looks like you're around here for sometime, so you should be knowing the rules of formatting your question, isn't it? Please do the needful. Thanks. :-)

Comment: They are similar for `PSERVER_DISPATCH` only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
typedef int SERVER_DISPATCH(struct _SERVER_OBJECT *pSerObj,int val);
typedef SERVER_DISPATCH *PSERVER_DISPATCH;
```

`SERVER_DISPATCH` is a function which returns int.

`PSERVER_DISPATCH` is a pointer to `SERVER_DISPATCH`: so it is a pointer to a function which returns int.

```
typedef int (*SERVER_DISPATCH)(struct _SERVER_OBJECT *pSerObj,int val);
typedef SERVER_DISPATCH PSERVER_DISPATCH;
```

`SERVER_DISPATCH` is a pointer to a function which returns int.

`PSERVER_DISPATCH` is a `SERVER_DISPATCH`: so it is a pointer to a function which returns int.

In both cases `PSERVER_DISPATCH` is the same. `SERVER_DISPATCH` is different.

Answer (score 0):

```
I think this is the process:

int function (int i)
{ 
return (i + 1);
}

typedef int (*fp)(int);  // Declare typedef

fp func = &function; // Define function-pointer variable, and initialize

int value = func(3);     // Call function through pointer
```

Comment: Actually I need some clarifucation in above two ways i represtended. weather they are similar

Answer (score 0):

Both versions are needlessly complex ways of writing:

```
typedef int (*PSERVER_DISPATCH)(struct _SERVER_OBJECT *pSerObj,int val);
```

Why you would ever need the type `SERVER_DISPATCH` from your examples, I have no idea. Seems like a pointless type that is never actually used by the program.

Comment: Regarding your "Why": With the none-P typedef you can define a prototype of your Implementation: (repelace "\\" with a newline) `typedef int FUNC(int, int);\\typedef FUNC *PFUNC;\\FUNC Function;\\void foo() { Function(2, 3); }\\int Function(int a, int b)  { return a + b; }` Without the `FUNC Function` there is no prototype what is risky.

Comment: @harper Do _not_ declare/define functions like that. That code is nothing but obfuscation. And there is no reason why you would ever want to do it.

Comment: Nope. When you have a bunch of module impelementing the same set of function interface (like WinCE StreamDriver) it's easy to define a consistent interface. (This StreamDriver interface is defined since a decade and will not change.)

Comment: @harper So? Just because it exists in a code base somewhere, it doesn't automatically turn into good programming practice.

Comment: So? Just because you don't use it, it doesn't automatically turn into a bad programming practice.

Comment: @harper Actually it does. If nobody else in the world is writing their C programs in the way you do, then they won't easily be able to read, understand and maintain your code. Microsoft Windows for example, has received plenty of criticism over the years for their strange Hungarian notation. Not even Microsoft themselves recommend using it any longer.

Comment: It isnt my way to write programs. Just found that in an OS by a company in Redmond. And it's logical, if PFUNC is the type of a pointer than FUNC should be of the type where a PFUNC points to. It may be inconvienient to you, but I doubt that you can tell that nobody uses this way witouth a prove.

Answer (score 0):

**typedef** are used to ease the reading of the code - especially for pointers to functions, or structure names.

```
typedef int myinteger;
typedef char *mystring;
typedef void (*myfunction)();
```

**use them like**

```
myinteger i;  
mystring s;
myfunction f;
```